# Error in my vector program (recursion)

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

Hi community when I run my script I receive the recursion error. I don't know how to go about it since my program is due in less than an hour. If someone can give me some insight that would be great! It is a two part script.

My code

```
import math
import random
from random import randrange, uniform

def add(u, v):
  sum1 = [x + y for x, y in zip(u, v)]
  return sum1

def negate(u):
  myng = [x - 2*y for x, y in zip(u, u)]
  return myng

def sub(u,v):
  d = [x - y for x, y in zip(u, v)]
  return d

def scalarMult(c, u):
  m = [(x+y-y)*c for x, y in zip(u,u)]
  return m

def zip(u,v):
  mt = [x * y for x, y in zip(u, v)]
  return mt

def dot(u, v):
  l = zp(u,v)
  a = sum(l)
  return a

def length(u):
  d = dot(u,u)
  x = math.sqrt(d)
  return x

def unit(v):
  l = length(v)
  m = [(x+y-y)/l for x,y in zip(v,v)]
  return m

def randVector(n, a, b):
  l = [] * n
  i = 0
  while(i<n):
    l.append(random.uniform(a,b))
    i=i+1

  return l



  #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#  VectorTest.py
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

import Vector

A = [-3, -4, 7]
B = [6, -2, 2]

print(A)
print(B)

print(Vector.add(A,B))
print(Vector.negate(B))
print(Vector.sub(A,B))
print(Vector.scalarMult(2.5,A))
print(Vector.scalarMult(-3.5,B))
print(Vector.zip(A,B))
print(Vector.dot(A,B))
print(Vector.length(A))
print(Vector.length(B))
print(Vector.unit(A))
print(Vector.unit(B))
print(Vector.angle(A,B))

C = Vector.randVector(3,-10,10)
print(Vector.sub(C,C))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `zip` function infinitely calls itself, generating an infinite recursion.

```
def zip(u, v):
    mt = [x * y for x, y in zip(u, v)]
    return mt
```

When you call it, it has to call itself to get its value. When it's called this way, it calls itself again and again, never completing.

Comment: Got it! Had to rename it. Thank you so much